# deal with an importer XNA

Tags: c#, xna

I added `test1.bin` to the content of my game. There is already a `test.bin` which works perfectly. The problem I have is :

> Erreur 11: Cannot autodetect which importer to use for
>   "Levels\test1.bin". There are no importers which handle this file
>   type. Specify the importer that handles this file type in your
>   project.

Answer (score 4):

The XNA Content Pipeline relies on the file extension in order to automatically determine which content importer and processor are appropriate for a given file.  There are no built-in importers or processors for `.bin` files, so unless you've defined some yourself, XNA can't figure out what you want to do with this file.

In Visual Studio, click on your `test.bin` file and view its properties in the property window.  There should be entries for the content importer and processor.  Make note of those values, then select your `test1.bin` file and make sure it's using the same settings.

Note that, if you're reading the raw data manually -- in other words, if you aren't using a `ContentManager` to load this file -- you need to set its **Build Action** to **None** and **Copy to Output Directory** to **Copy if Newer**.